# How to force applying css without using `!important`?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

The default font of my theme doesn’t support my language, so I replace it with a supported one by adding this on the style.css

```
@font-face {    font-family: 'LibreBaskerville';
    src: url('https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/wp-content/themes/the-thinker-lite-child/font/LibreBaskervilleF-Regular.ttf');
    url('https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/wp-content/themes/the-thinker-lite-child/font/LibreBaskervilleF-Regular.woff') format('woff'); 
}
```

However, one plugin still uses the default font:

[image]

[I asked the authors](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/font-registered-in-style-css-isnt-recognized/) and they say there is no way around this besides using

```
* { font-family: "LibreBaskerville" !important;}
```

or copy what my theme is doing to override it:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {font-family: "LibreBaskerville";}
```

I find both solutions don't get to the root of the problem. Is there a better way to do so?

[Here is the page for you to examine.](https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/mot-so-suy-nghi-tu-du-an-chu-vn-song-song?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=Ch%E1%BB%AF%20VN%20song%20song&utm_campaign=Get%20help)

Comment: Just checked your site. It looks like *DejaVu Serif* gets only applied to the arrow in first paragraph, the remainder of the text uses *LibreBaskervilleF-Regular*. So did you fix your issue?

Comment: Why is the *theme method* a problem? I understand not wanting to use important, but if you have all the rules there, then it should be an easy fix?

Comment: @Gh05d yes, I'm using the suggested solution (the second one) in the question to fix it for now, but I'd like a better solution

Comment: @Stender I'm not sure. That's what the plugin author told me.

Comment: Like the plugin author writes, they have nothing to do with font selection - But any decent theme should have settings where you can select/upload your font?

Comment: Can't you just overwrite it using it's css selector `wp-block-kadence-accordion alignnone`?

Comment: @Gh05d using `kt-blocks-accordion-title` works, but when the plugin updates in the future, will it break again?

Comment: @Stender no, this theme doesn't have that setting

Comment: @Ooker if they update their class names, then unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select everything inside the accordion, but not overwrite the entire theme with important, you can make your selector like this

`.wp-block-kadence-accordion * {     font-family: "LibreBaskerville"; }`

This is not likely to change in classnames, but not unthinkable either`